# How to splice two sources of data (or append an argument to a dynamic argument list)?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

Suppose I have many files such as:

```
filetypea34
filetypeb34
somemoredata34
filetypea35
filetypeb35
somemoredata35
... and so on
```

and I want to move all of these files (but not the entire directory) to a new directory. Or delete them. Knowing that the files as expanded by the shell with `*34` is a representative "slice":

```
ls *34 | sed 's/34/\*/g' | xargs mv target_dir
```

This would work great for if I wanted to delete them, but I want to move them to a new directory. The command above executes the commands

```
mv target_dir filetypea* 
mv target_dir filetypeb* 
mv target_dir somemoredata*
```

which is clearly not going to work.

How can I reorder arguments? I see that something that works like the reverse of `tee` would get this done, e.g. a program that takes a stream and an argument and writes the stream out and then the argument (or writes the argument and then the stream) to its output stream.

Another alternative would be if `xargs` allows me to specify that `target_dir` is an argument to stick at the end of the arglist. (though right now `xargs` is calling mv 3 times and I'm not even sure how to tell it to make it into one mv call)

Comment: `mv $(echo *34 | sed s/34/\*/g) target_dir` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the `sed` is. `mv *34 target_dir` should work.

Comment: the purpose is to make a list of all the various files (there are 3 (`n`, really) types of files which have some number appended to each of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `-n` and `-I` options of `xargs`

```
ls *34 | sed 's/34/\*/g' | xargs -n 1 -I file mv file target_dir
```

**Note :** It's not a good practice to parse output of `ls`

Comment: Sounds like a lot of the issues there (such as newlines in a filename --- what the frack? that's just asking for trouble.) would still crop up even when using a "better" way. like maybe `find`?

Comment: @StevenLu: (GNU) `find` has `-print0` and (GNU) `xargs` has `-0`.

Comment: Ah yes. That does make it quite robust. I'm actually pretty surprised that shells can handle NULs in strings

Answer (score 2):

You need the `-t` option for `mv`.

```
command1 | command2 | xargs mv -t target_dir
```

From `man mv`:

```
   mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

   ...

   -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

---

EDIT: If your variant of `mv` doesn't support `-t`, you could say:

```
   ... | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} target_dir
```

Comment: Note that `-t` isn't specified by POSIX; GNU `mv` has it, BSD `mv` does not.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Updated to provide an alternative in case `-t` isn't supported.

Comment: thanks, the `-I` for `xargs` is what I needed to know

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `sed` or `xargs`. `mv` can take more than 2 arguments, in which case all but the last are treated as file names to move to the directory named by the last argument.

```
for f in *34; do
    mv ${f%34}* target_dir
done
```

Comment: Ah. So you want to move any file that begins with `foo` if there exists a file named `foo34`, correct? (Where `foo` is any prefix at all?

Comment: Yeah. admittedly I could have written the example better. The specific use case is a single dir that has some shell scripts in it, which generate mountains of very similarly named files to the script's name itself (but which have various numbers appended to them). It makes it hard to do operations on the non-needle part of the haystack